# How to determine which GCP region in the US is best for a global user base?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Dockerized API service destined to run using Cloud Run. The service is backed by Firestore. It's a startup project aimed at English speaking customers most likely US and UK.

In the follow article (https://cloud.google.com/solutions/best-practices-compute-engine-region-selection) it says "For a global user base, deploy in a region in the US".

Hosting the API Service and Firestore in the same region seems to make sense. In the article it says "Estimate 1 ms of round-trip latency for every 100 km traveled". Based on that, I would pick the East side of the US because that's nearer on the map to the UK. I assume the undersea cables terminate at the coast. However, maybe the UK is linked directly to another part of the US. What particular region within the US that would be most suitable and how do you arrive at this? (does it even matter?)

Comment: Maybe worth doing some tests yourself.

Comment: In the real world, it will not matter. There are many factors such as the number of hops from a user to the nearest access port for one of the Google network interconnects. The type of network connection (wireless versus Ethernet), the speed of the intermediate routers, etc.